# maximum limit of steps passed in ALM

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I am trying to run ALM test cases with 1095 steps in single test case. But it throws an error ,What is the maximum limit of steps to be passed in a single test case in ALM ?

Answer (score 0):

**500** is a maximum limit of steps can be passed in one single test case.

```
Example: If there are 1000 steps in one test cases it can be split into two test cases and run it
```